# Pandas won't recognize date while reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, datetime

I'm working on a script which reads in a .csv file with pandas and fills in a specific form.
One column in the .csv file is a birthday-column.

While reading the .csv I parse it with 'parse_dates' to get a datetime object so i can format it for my needs:

```
df = pd.read_csv('readfile1.csv',sep=';', parse_dates=['birthday'])
```

While it works perfectly with readfile1.csv, it won't work with readfile2.csv. But these files look exactly the same.

The error i get makes me think that the automatic parsing to datetime through pandas is not working:

```
print(df.at[i,'birthday'].strftime("%d%m%Y"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

In both cases the format of the birthday looks like:

```
'1965-05-16T12:00:00.000Z' #from readfile1.csv
'1934-04-06T11:00:00.000Z' #from readfile2.csv
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I checked the encoding of the files and both are 'UTF-8'. Any ideas?

Thank you!
Greetings

Comment: with a df.info(), what type do you get for column birthday?

Comment: Dtype is 'object' for readfile2. readfile1: datetime64[ns, UTC]

Comment: if you do not set keyword `parse_dates`, and convert the column after reading the csv, with `pd.to_datetime` and keyword `errors='coerce'`, what result do you get? does the column have `NaT` values?

Comment: I just did exactly that. The problem was a faulty date. 1077-11-19T12:00:00.000Z which caused:
```File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 113, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1077-11-19 12:00:00
```

Comment: great :) If you have more than one faulty timestamp, the method I described can be helpful as well since you can easily find all cells (string col where the datetime col is `NaT`).

Comment: So seems like all of your datas in the chosen column have to be in the right format. In my opinion that's more of a problem why such a date is even accepted in the first place :D

Explicitly calling the ```pd.to_datetime``` was definetly the right way, to have a better error message.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> if you do not set keyword parse_dates, and convert the column after
> reading the csv, with pd.to_datetime and keyword errors='coerce', what
> result do you get? does the column have NaT values? – MrFuppes 32 mins
> ago

MrFuppes comment on calling pd.to_datetime led to success. One faulty date in the column was the cause of the error. Also Lumber Jacks's hint was helpful to determine the datatypes!